# gnuplot plot nth point for 2D vector plot

Tags: gnuplot

For 1D plots, I know I can plot every nth point using:

```
plot "data" every 8 using 1:2
```

However I want to do the same for a 2D vector plot. Currently I am doing (e.g.):

```
plot "temp" every 8 using 1:2:5:6 with vector nohead
```

though this just plots every nth point in the y-direction, not for x and y. If not, is there a quick awk oneliner to fix the input file?

[image: every 2 points]
[image: every 4 points]
[image: every 8 points]

Comment: It could be as simple as using `every 8:Y` (Y being the block increment) if your data file is organized into blocks.  Otherwise it might require reformatting your data file--I should point out that we can't really give you a `quick awk one-liner` without seeing how your data file is formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your data is formatted in blocks, i.e. different x-values are separated by an empty line:

```
x0 y0
x0 y1
x0 y2 
...
x0 yn

x1 y0
x1 y2
...
```

In that case, using `every 8` only selects every eighth point in every block (those unit separated by empty lines). So you must also select every eighth block with `every 8:8`:

```
plot "temp" every 8:8 using 1:2:5:6 with vector nohead
```

That behavior doesn't depend on the plotting style, but only on the data file format.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I need. I had previously tried `every 2,2` but that didn't work.